# Retrieving from Firebase Database does not work to String, but it works in long

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My 3 `long` is reading but my `TextView String` (s) are returning as null.

This is the code for adding a new user data:

```
public void addNewUser(String email, String address, String username, String interests, String website, String bio, String profile_photo){

    User user = new User(userID, address, 1, email, StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username));

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(user);

    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(
            bio,
            username,
            0,
            interests,
            profile_photo,
            0,
            0,
            StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username),
            website
    );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users_account_settings))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(settings);
}
```

This is the code for retrieving User's data from Firebase Database:

```
public UserSettings getUserSettings(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    Log.d(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: retrieving user_accounter_settings from firebase.");

    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings();
    User user = new User();

    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        //users node
        if (ds.getKey().equals(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))){
            Log.d(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: datasnapshot: " + ds);

            try{
                user.setUsername(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(User.class)
                                .getUsername()
                );
                user.setEmail(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(User.class)
                                .getEmail()
                );
                user.setPhone_number(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(User.class)
                                .getPhone_number()
                );
                user.setUser_id(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(User.class)
                                .getUser_id()
                );
                user.setAddress(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(User.class)
                                .getAddress()
                );

                Log.d(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: users information: " + user.toString());
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            //user_account_settings node
            if (ds.getKey().equals(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users_account_settings))) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: datasnapshot: " + ds);

                settings.setDisplay_name(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getDisplay_name()
                );
                settings.setUsername(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getUsername()
                );
                settings.setWebsite(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getWebsite()
                );
                settings.setInterests(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getInterests()
                );
                settings.setProfile_photo(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getProfile_photo()
                );
                settings.setBio(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getBio()
                );
                settings.setTrustworthy(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getTrustworthy()
                );
                settings.setTruefans(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getTruefans()
                );
                settings.setFollowers(
                        ds.child(userID)
                                .getValue(UserAccountSettings.class)
                                .getFollowers()
                );

                Log.d(TAG, "getUserAccountSettings: retrieved user_account_settings information: " + settings.toString());

            }
        }

    }

    return new UserSettings(user, settings);
}
```

This is the code for UserAccountSettings class:

```
public class UserAccountSettings {

private String bio;
private String display_name;
private long followers;
private String interests;
private String profile_photo;
private long truefans;
private long trustworthy;
private String username;
private String website;

public UserAccountSettings(String bio, String display_name, long followers, String interests, String profile_photo, long truefans, long trustworthy, String username, String website) {
    this.bio = bio;
    this.display_name = display_name;
    this.followers = followers;
    this.interests = interests;
    this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
    this.truefans = truefans;
    this.trustworthy = trustworthy;
    this.username = username;
    this.website = website;
}

public UserAccountSettings() {

}

public String getBio() {
    return bio;
}

public void setBio(String bio) {
    this.bio = bio;
}

public String getDisplay_name() {
    return display_name;
}

public void setDisplay_name(String display_name)     {
    this.display_name = display_name;
}

public long getFollowers() {
    return followers;
}

public void setFollowers(long followers) {
    this.followers = followers;
}

public String getInterests() {
    return interests;
}

public void setInterests(String interests) {
    this.interests = interests;
}

public String getProfile_photo() {
    return profile_photo;
}

public void setProfile_photo(String profile_photo) {
    this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
}

public long getTruefans() {
    return truefans;
}

public void setTruefans(long truefans) {
    this.truefans = truefans;
}

public long getTrustworthy() {
    return trustworthy;
}

public void setTrustworthy(long trustworthy) {
    this.trustworthy = trustworthy;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UserAccountSettings{" +
            "bio='" + bio + '\'' +
            ", display_name='" + display_name + '\'' +
            ", followers=" + followers +
            ", interests='" + interests + '\'' +
            ", profile_photo='" + profile_photo + '\'' +
            ", truefans=" + truefans +
            ", trustworthy=" + trustworthy +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", website='" + website + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

This is the code for `setProfileWidgets` method:

```
private void setProfileWidgets(UserSettings userSettings){
    Log.d(TAG, "setProfileWidgets: settings widgets with data retrieving from firebase database: " + userSettings.toString());

    //User user = userSettings.getUser();
    UserAccountSettings settings = userSettings.getSettings();

    //UniversalImageLoader.setImage(settings.getProfile_photo(), mProfilePhoto, null , "");

    mDisplayname.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getDisplay_name()));
    mUsername.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getUsername()));
    mBio.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getBio()));
    mIntersts.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInterests()));
    mWebsite.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getWebsite()));
    mTruefans.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getTruefans()));
    mTrustworthy.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getTrustworthy()));
    mFollowers.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getFollowers()));
}
```

My `addValueEventListener` method:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //retrieve user inforation from the database
            setProfileWidgets(mFirebaseMethod.getUserSettings(dataSnapshot));

            //retrieve images for the user in question

        }
```

This is the image for my Data Structure in Firebase Database:

[image]

This is the image for resulting as `null` in my Android Emulator: And it suppose to be display the username.

[image]

Thank you!

> In the top, I did not apply the Asynchronous Firebase API. Below, I just added it. If you are little confuse, let me know.

This is the code when applying the Asynchronous Firebase API:

```
private void readData(final FirebaseCallback firebaseCallback) {

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            setProfileWidgets(mFirebaseMethod.getUserSettings(dataSnapshot));

            firebaseCallback.onCallback();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}

private interface FirebaseCallback{
    void onCallback();
}
```

Here is for the `onCreateView` method for `readData`:

```
readData(new FirebaseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCallback: ");
        }
    });
```

Is there anything I missing? Let me know, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by variables are "returning null"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Comment: Please do NOT include images in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @NicoHaase It give as null, instead of the data. For example my username must print it as "raemarc.san.gabriel" but it print as "null"

Comment: But my 3 long it works(The truefans, followers, trustworthy". It print it out correctly.

Comment: @AlexMamo hey, sorry for interrupting you. Is this related to Asynchronous Firebase API? Thank you

Comment: @MiraquelSayson Yes, it is.

Comment: @AlexMamo Ow, thank you! Could you tell me how to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: @AlexMamo I just want to ask something. But why my 3 `long` is returning correctly?

Comment: Just a beginner. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexMamo I added my code for applying Asynchronous Firebase API in my question. Still getting null. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check if your `myRef` is pointing to the correct node, better yet if you just use the user id itself instead of getting all the children of the node. Your `getUserSettings()` should also check/handle if the dataSnapshot passed is null.